# Concatenating objects with linq

Tags: linq

I have a class like this

```
public class test{
        public string a { get; set; }
        public string b { get; set; }
}
```

and a list of objects

```
List<test> list= new List<test>();
list.Add(new test() {a = "1a", b = "1b" });
list.Add(new test() {a = "2a", b = "2b" });
...
```

i want concatenate the elements and have a string like

```
"1a 1b + 2a 2b" ... etc
```

Can i use Linq to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in Linq by mapping to a string as follows.

```
string Result =
    String.Join(" + ", 
        list.Select(iObj => String.Format("{0} {1}", iObj.a, iObj.b)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String.Join(" + ", list.Select(x => /*What you want*/));
```

will do the trick!